# Stress on the verbs like сердить and пустить

Tags: грамматика, глаголы, ударение

Regular verbs that end in и́ть in the infinitive (the stress is on the final syllable) and in ишь in the second person singular, may have a fixed stress (like говори́ть - ты говори́шь) or a non-fixed stress (like люби́ть - ты лю́бишь). If they have Slavonic palatalization (for instance, утверди́ть has Slavonic palatalization because it has the form утверждённый and not утвержённый), we know that they have fixed stress. Otherwise, there doesn't seem to be any general rule.

Nevertheless, in a grammar for non-Russian native speakers, I found the following rule (if I understood it correctly): For regular verbs that end in и́ть in the infinitive (with stress on the final syllable) and in ишь in the second person singular, if the radical ends in two consonants, then the stress is fixed. As an example of the application of this rule, we have: ты возвести́шь and not ты возве́стишь.
Three exceptions are given (and it's formulated in a way that suggests that the list is exhaustive): дразни́ть, корми́ть and пусти́ть (and verbs derived from them).

But applying this rule, we should have: ты серди́шь, yet we have ты се́рдишь. So, I'm wondering if the author just forgot some exceptions or if I misunderstood the rule... Do you know of any other examples like дразни́ть, корми́ть, пусти́ть (and серди́ть?) with non-fixed stress that end in two consonants?

Comment: Could you please expand a little bit more on the palatalization part? _Утверди́ть/утверди́шь_ is not an exception to the rule you're mentioning.

Comment: @Quassnoi Indeed, it is a bit confusing. The point is: for such verbs (independently of the fact that they end with two consonants or not) that have Slavonic palatalization, we know that the accent is fixed (in my grammar they are not considered in the same category of verbs as the other ones); then the question arises only for those verbs without Slavonic palatalization. I could remove the reference to Slavonic palatalization or I will try to edit my question in a clearer way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to your examples, I found these:

- винти́ть – ви́нтишь (и винти́шь)
- черти́ть – че́ртишь
- крести́ть – кре́стишь
- скобли́ть – ско́блишь (и скобли́шь)

I used the following query:

[https://gramdict.ru/search/*ить?stress=c](https://gramdict.ru/search/*%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C?stress=c)

In the past few hundred years many verbs have changed their stress in the 2nd and 3rd persons from the ending to the root, and it's still an ongoing process. More on this here: https://github.com/gramdict/zalizniak-2010/issues/47

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/винтить gives винти́шь?!

Comment: The grammar is more than 25 years old. It says that the contemporary tendency of Russian is to develop for such verbs (regular verbs in -ишь) non-fixed ударение. So, maybe for винти́ть and скобли́ть, the original ударение was fixed and the non-fixed variant is more recent? Then for these two verbs, we could consider it was not an omission by the author of the grammar. How does it sound for native Russian speakers?

Comment: @Bruno, Zalizniak's _Grammatical Dictionary of Russian_ which I referred to in my answer is 47 years old now (first published in 1977).

Answer (score 2):

Sergey's post answers your question well.

I'll post this because it's too long for a comment thread to Sergey's answer, and because it does elaborate on some parts of your question and the follow-up in the comments:

1. There are several verbs with variability in stress both in the infinitive and in the finite forms: *оки́слить/окисли́ть, ско́блить/скобли́ть, те́плить/тепли́ть*.

   *Ско́блить* (the infinitive) has completely fallen out of use in the modern language, and the finite forms with the stress on the penultimate syllable (*ско́блит, ско́блишь* etc.) are used almost exclusively in poetry.

   *Те́плить* "to burn (something) dimly" and *тепли́ть* ("to make warm, to insulate") mean different things. So do *оки́слить* "to oxidize" and *окисли́ть* "to make sour".
2. Russian stress is extremely mobile indeed. For some verbs like *сверлить, долбить* etc. most dictionaries only list *сверли́шь, долби́шь* as valid stress patterns, but many (if not most) speakers use *све́рлишь, до́лбишь* in speech.

   Some exceptions mentioned by Sergey (*че́ртишь, ви́нтишь, кре́стишь*) were not considered valid for literary use until the XX century. The popular song [*Кру́тится, ве́ртится шар голубой*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9) (better known in the West by its Yiddish cover, *Vu iz dus gesele*) has been criticized for its use of the vernacular stress pattern. *Крутить* and *вертеть* are not related to your question, but it's a good demonstration of the overall principle.
3. The derivatives of the verbs with the prefix *вы-* put the stress on the prefix: *вы́пустишь, вы́кормишь, вы́чертишь* etc.

Comment: The point 3 is a bit off-topic because it is not about verbs that have the ударение in the final in the infinitive and I remember I was very happy to learn there was such an easy rule! Indeed, as a non-Russian native speaker the ударение is one of the most difficult things to grasp, especially because they don't appear in texts (and, since my learning is essentially by reading texts, I am always confused with the ударение). I was wondering how grammars can know where the ударение is (for old words that are not used nowadays) if the ударение never appears in texts.

Comment: @Bruno: well, you did mention "verbs that derive from them" so I thought I would mention that too for the sake of completeness. Analyzing the stress is indeed tricky. If you can read Russian, you might find Zaliznyak's _От праславянской акцентуации к русской_ an interesting read. It's available [online](https://inslav.ru/images/stories/pdf/1985_Zalizniak.pdf). It's a diachronic analysis of Russian stress, full of very slick tricks.